# How do I identify source of element.style injected on hover?

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I have an Elementor site. I know some HTML and CSS. But I don't know how to identify (I suppose) the Elementor file that has the code that injects inline CSS code on the submenu items on hover. I know how to identify the external CSS sources, but not this one that is hardcoded on hover.

[image]

Don't know if I can see the source using the browser web inspector as I can see the external CSS sorce.

Hope maybe someone can give me a hand on this. Appreciated.

Comment: That would have to come from one of the JavaScripts the theme is using then.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm using 'Hello Elementor' theme, which's supposed not to add extra code, only normalize the content.

I will check it out, I only searched on the Elementor plugin's folder, not in the Theme's one. I will let you know if I finally find it there. Thank you.

Comment: @CBroe There isn't any JavaScript on the 'Hello Elementor' Theme. Not even in the Child Theme. Here some screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/LKFsxwP

All I found was about theme structure. No functions even related to that injection. Any other idea where this may come from? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the Nav Menu Widget? Then it is probably coming from there.

Comment: Yes! Thank you.